# Filter out phone numbers from Google Sheets query using regexreplace?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a [list of number](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fhYVYvK0EBK1S6VYbpzYhOGNKIHKFw8UP7_jRZg3hgY/edit#gid=523946874) using this query formula.

```
=query(uploadData!A:M,"Select B, C, H, I, M where not(C) contains '"&JOIN("|",filter!A:A)&"' and  B contains 'Incoming' and not B is null and not H is null ",1)
```

You can see I'm trying to filter the results so as to NOT include any matching numbers found in `filter!A:A`. However, it doesn't like the fact that the result and filter sheet use the telephone number format `(###) ###-####`.

I believe using regexreplace will help resolve this issue but I'm not knowledgeable enough with regexreplace to know how to incorporate it.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, google sheets query understand pipes `|` as OR logic, so you may rty this formula instead:

`=query(uploadData!A:M,"Select B, C, H, I, M where not C contains '"&JOIN("' and not C contains '",filter(filter!A2:A,filter!A2:A<>""))&"' and  B contains 'Incoming' and not B is null and not H is null ",1)`

---

I used `JOIN("' and not C contains '",filter(filter!A2:A,filter!A2:A<>""))`:

- `join` + `"' and not C contains '"` to get all conditions one by one
- `filter(filter!A2:A,filter!A2:A<>"")` to have only not empty cells

Comment: Is there a way to filter out column M if the duration value is 0? I tried some simple things like `not M contains '00:00:00.000'` and also `M > 0` and also `not M contains '12:00:00 AM'` and none of them worked.

Comment: I think, it's better to post another question for that.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks for your help.